# Referring to specific template specialization from a non-instantiated context: instantiation or not?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization, template-instantiation

Consider the following example

```
template <typename A> struct S 
{
  A a;
  void foo() {}
};  

template <typename T> void bar()
{
  S<void> *p = 0;
}

template <typename T> void baz()
{
  S<void>{}.foo();
}

template <typename T> void qux()
{
  S<void> s{};
}

int main()
{
}
```

Function templates `bar`, `baz` and `qux` are deliberately left non-instantiated.

The definition of `baz` fails to compile in GCC and Clang for "obvious" reason - `S<void>` is an invalid specialization of `S`. However, which language rule is working in this case?

1. On the one hand, `S<void>` does not depend on template parameters of `baz`, member access requires it to be complete, which triggers instantiation of `S<void>`, which fails. Diagnostic is required.
2. On the other hand we have the blanket rule of "if no valid specialization can be generated for a non-instantiated template, the code is ill-formed". This makes the definition of `baz` ill-formed. However, no diagnostic is required.

More specifically, am I correct in my assumption (as expressed in #1) that the above reference to `S<void>` from non-instantiated `baz` requires instantiation of `S<void>`? The assumption is supported by the fact that both compilers happily accept the definition of `bar`, which does not instantiate `S<void>`.

However, the aforementioned compilers differ in their treatment of `qux` - Clang complains, while GCC accepts it without any complaints. Is this a bug in one of the compilers? Is diagnostic required in this case? Or am I wrong in my assumption that #1 is at work here? If #2 is the basis for the diagnostic, then the difference between the compilers is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

For both `baz` and `qux`, the validity of the expression including `S<void>` can only be done through instantiation of S. Nevertheless, compilers are not mandated to perform this validation before any instantiation [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.4)

> The validity of a template **may** *be checked* prior to any instantiation.
>   [...
>    ] The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition *would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter*,

Answer (score 1):

Both `S<void>{}` and `S<void> s{}` are used in a context that requires the instantiation of `S<void>`, such an instantiation is *ill-formed* due to the member having incomplete type `void`.

The relevant quotes are `[temp.inst]/1`:

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program. [...]

and `[temp.arg]/6`:

> If the use of a template-argument gives rise to an ill-formed construct in the instantiation of a template specialization, the program is ill-formed.

On the other hand both `baz` and `quz` are *ill-formed* NDR
`[temp.res]/8`:

> Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> **(8.1) no valid specialization can be generated for a template**, [...]